# Test for richness accross samples with vegan

Tags: r, vegan

How can I test the differences between species richness (table below) using means (S.obs) and standard deviation (se.obs) with vegan or any other package in R?

```
 "Group.1"                "S.obs"   "se.obs"
 "Cliona celata complex"  499.7143  59.32867 
 "Cliona viridis"         285.5000  51.68736 
 "Dysidea fragilis"       358.6667  61.03096 
 "Phorbas fictitius"      525.9167  24.66763
```

Thank you in advance!
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the technical point of view, this looks very much like *t*-test with unequal variances. Check the formula, and plug in your data. The R function `t.test()` expects raw data, but if you already have means and se's, it is easy to calculate statistics by hand.

I have no idea how you obtained your numbers and therefore I cannot comment on the scientific point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, being that it was outputted by vegan, I fount out it can be ANOVA tested in the following way:

```
 richness.aov <- aov(specnumber(dataset))
 summary(richness.aov)
 #Tukey multiple comparisons of means
 #95% family-wise confidence level
 TukeyHSD(richness.aov)
```

Thank you all anyhow!

Comment: You didn't tell us that it was output from vegan -- and it wasn't. No vegan function outputs items `"S.obs"` and `"se.obs"`. The `specnumber()`  function certainly produces data you can analyse with `aov()`, but not the data you displayed in your original query.

Comment: Indeed you are right Dr. Oksanen, that was derived from an output of estimateR. Sorry for the lapse, I am a begginer but my intentions are good :)